# Not able to print JSON object String in android TextView

Tags: java, android, json

So I am trying to fetch JSON string from a website which looks like this

```
[{"name":"Painting"},{"name":"Painting or varnishing doors"},{"name":"Painting or varnishing frames"},{"name":"Varnishing floors"},{"name":"Picking old wallpaper"},{"name":"Painting the facade"},{"name":"professional athlete"}]
```

I just want to fetch the first JSONObject with the string "Painting".

Here's my MainActivity.java code

```
package mobiletest.pixelapp.com.mobiletest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import model.Cup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private String myString;
    private String anotherString;
    private String myVar;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Cup myCup = new Cup();
    String newString = myCup.myMethod();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(newString);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        Log.v("Key",jsonObject.getString("name"));
        textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
   }
```

Here's my java class file cup.java

```
package model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * Created by pruthvi on 12/2/2015.
 */
public class Cup {
    public String myMethod()
    {
        String output  = getUrlContents("http://xyz.co/tests/android-query.php");
        return output;
    }

    private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        // many of these calls can throw exceptions, so i've just
        // wrapped them all in one try/catch statement.
        try
        {
            // create a url object
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);

            // create a urlconnection object
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

            // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

Now the problem, when I run this code as java I am easily able to print painting from the JSONObject, but when I try to run it as an android view by setting the text for my TextView, I am getting some strange system.err

```
12-02 14:06:26.809 19250-19250/mobiletest.pixelapp.com.mobiletest D/libc: [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 10, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
12-02 14:06:26.809 19250-19250/mobiletest.pixelapp.com.mobiletest W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:393)
12-02 14:06:26.809 19250-19250/mobiletest.pixelapp.com.mobiletest W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:244)
12-02 14:06:26.809 19250-19250/mobiletest.pixelapp.com.mobiletest W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:219)
```

I am new to java and android, and as of now I just want to get data from my remote server files and database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your server name value is null.. check that value

Comment: Also the given URL is giving 404 error..

Comment: try to run your server side code inside sub thread not on main thread

Comment: As I have said, this program is running quite well as Java program, but not with android. I am able to get the string from my server and print it.

Comment: For better approach use `asynctask` .

Comment: In Android, you are dealing with two different thing at one time i.e. User Interface(including buttos, textview etc) and at the same time you are trying to execute the php read the json data. That' s the problem in your progam. You ALWAYS have to use  AsnycTask while dealing with url. Create a new thread line runOnUiThread() and then execute your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this example it will give you an idea

```
 AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncLoad = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t="
                        + TITLE);
                String URL2="http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=saw";
                Log.d("URL content", url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                Log.d("URL content", "register URL");
                urlConnection.connect();
                Log.d("URL connection", "establish connection");

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        };

        asyncLoad.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like that in onCrate Method

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(newString);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = jsonObject.getString("name")
    textView.setText(name));}
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It will set name to textView.
Happy to Help and Happy Coding

Comment: If you see the JSON string, you shall find all the objects with the same key word "name". How can I then run it in for loop and set the text? when I just have one TextView created in my main xml file

Comment: If you have to display all items of json array, then you have to use listView to display all name. What you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do network task in UI Thread.
So

```
 String newString = myCup.myMethod();
```

not properly working.

Main Reason of those errors are related with thread context.

If you want to do network task with android, use async task or other network library (personally I recommend `retrofit`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 try 
    {
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(newString);

     if(jarray.length()>0){

     String name = jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
     displayName(name);   //new method
    }catch(Exception e){
}
```

Define the method **displayName(String)** like this outside onCreate()

```
public void displayName(final  String name){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

        textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));

         }
    });
}
```